# Parsing a Json to a ListView

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio

I have this json form this URL: [Website Here](https://api.blockcypher.com/v1/btc/main/txs/b6f6991d03df0e2e04dafffcd6bc418aac66049e2cd74b80f14ac86db1e3f0da)

The problem is that I'm trying to retrieve some of the data in the JSON like:  block_height, total, fees and size. I have 2 days trying to make it work but I have no idea why my code is not working. The last I've tried was showing the data in a alert dialog. But this isn't working yet.

JSON:

```
{
  "block_hash": "0000000000000397a165d83cc4640321a3b8ff4cce1f8aa2570deabf14ac14e7",
  "block_height": 154598,
  "block_index": 63,
  "hash": "b6f6991d03df0e2e04dafffcd6bc418aac66049e2cd74b80f14ac86db1e3f0da",
  "addresses": [
    "13AMPUTTwryLGX3nrMvumaerSqNXkL3gEV",
    "14pDqB95GWLWCjFxM4t96H2kXH7QMKSsgG",
    "1FwYmGEjXhMtxpWDpUXwLx7ndLNfFQncKq"
  ],
  "total": 100000000,
  "fees": 0,
  "size": 258,
  "preference": "low",
  "confirmed": "2011-11-24T11:45:54Z",
  "received": "2011-11-24T11:45:54Z",
  "ver": 1,
  "double_spend": false,
  "vin_sz": 1,
  "vout_sz": 2,
  "confirmations": 339633,
  "confidence": 1,
  "inputs": [
    {
      "prev_hash": "9fa4e0e33aba41623bc3618827d2a6495e6828ce04f26c97771a1369210e8201",
      "output_index": 2,
      "script": "48304502210098a2851420e4daba656fd79cb60cb565bd7218b6b117fda9a512ffbf17f8f178022005c61f31fef3ce3f906eb672e05b65f506045a65a80431b5eaf28e0999266993014104f0f86fa57c424deb160d0fc7693f13fce5ed6542c29483c51953e4fa87ebf247487ed79b1ddcf3de66b182217fcaf3fcef3fcb44737eb93b1fcb8927ebecea26",
      "output_value": 100000000,
      "sequence": 4294967295,
      "addresses": [
        "1FwYmGEjXhMtxpWDpUXwLx7ndLNfFQncKq"
      ],
      "script_type": "pay-to-pubkey-hash",
      "age": 154567
    }
  ],
  "outputs": [
    {
      "value": 98000000,
      "script": "76a91429d6a3540acfa0a950bef2bfdc75cd51c24390fd88ac",
      "spent_by": "df0f8a4f0988de2875705a79ec826c8b9f8b08c9ffa4e5b4a5ea1b7bf956306c",
      "addresses": [
        "14pDqB95GWLWCjFxM4t96H2kXH7QMKSsgG"
      ],
      "script_type": "pay-to-pubkey-hash"
    },
    {
      "value": 2000000,
      "script": "76a91417b5038a413f5c5ee288caa64cfab35a0c01914e88ac",
      "spent_by": "0c45329983279acf2f9e9c7976774ef11bdb2646d934836c53e6679281e09ac8",
      "addresses": [
        "13AMPUTTwryLGX3nrMvumaerSqNXkL3gEV"
      ],
      "script_type": "pay-to-pubkey-hash"
    }
  ]
}
```

JAVA - Android Studio Fragment

```
 private void setUpData() {
        // Retrieve the city data from the web service
        // In a worker thread since it's a network operation.
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    retrieveData();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Cannot retrive Data", e);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }



    protected void retrieveData() throws IOException {
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        final StringBuilder json = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            // Connect to the web service
            URL url = new URL("https://api.blockcypher.com/v1/btc/main/txs/"+TxsHashs);
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());

            // Read the JSON data into the StringBuilder
            int read;
            char[] buff = new char[1024];
            while ((read = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
                json.append(buff, 0, read);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error connecting to service", e);
            throw new IOException("Error connecting to service", e);
        }
        // Create markers for the city data.
        // Must run this on the UI thread since it's a UI operation.


        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    DataAdapter(json.toString());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error processing JSON", e);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void DataAdapter(String json)
    {
        try
        {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
            String block_height = jsonObject.getString("block_height");
            String total = jsonObject.getString("total");
            String fee = jsonObject.getString("fee");
            String size = jsonObject.getString("size");
            String received = jsonObject.getString("received");
            String confirmations = jsonObject.getString("confirmations");

            showalert(TxsHashs,received);
        }
        catch (JSONException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

 private void showalert(String title, String msj)
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder MSGbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        MSGbox.setTitle(title);
        String mensaje = msj;
        MSGbox.setMessage(mensaje)
                .setPositiveButton("OKEY", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alertDialog = MSGbox.create();
        alertDialog.show();
    }
```

Please, someone Help Me

Comment: put your logcat ,  what error do you get?

Comment: Why aren't you using JsonArray and JsonObject? Those provided methods help you work with Json easily.

Comment: @RayLi He's using JSONObject

Comment: Sorry, didn't scroll down and see all the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Link to the working code](https://github.com/Stabja/ParseCypherJson)

Add these to the build.gradle

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
```

Create 3 model classes for Cyphers, Inputs, Outputs

```
package com.project.blockcypher.models;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
import java.util.List;

public class Cyphers {
    @SerializedName("block_height")
    private int block_height;
    @SerializedName("block_index")
    private int block_index;
    @SerializedName("hash")
    private String hash;
    @SerializedName("addresses")
    private List<String> addresses;
    @SerializedName("total")
    private int total;
    @SerializedName("fees")
    private int fees;
    @SerializedName("size")
    private int size;
    @SerializedName("preference")
    private String preference;
    @SerializedName("relayed_by")
    private String relayed_by;
    @SerializedName("received")
    private String received;
    @SerializedName("ver")
    private int ver;
    @SerializedName("double_spend")
    private boolean double_spend;
    @SerializedName("vin_sz")
    private int vin_sz;
    @SerializedName("vout_sz")
    private int vout_sz;
    @SerializedName("confirmations")
    private int confirmations;
    @SerializedName("inputs")
    private List<Inputs> inputs;
    @SerializedName("outputs")
    private List<Outputs> outputs;

    public int getBlock_height() {
        return block_height;
    }

    public void setBlock_height(int block_height) {
        this.block_height = block_height;
    }

    public int getBlock_index() {
        return block_index;
    }

    public void setBlock_index(int block_index) {
        this.block_index = block_index;
    }

    public String getHash() {
        return hash;
    }

    public void setHash(String hash) {
        this.hash = hash;
    }

    public List<String> getAddresses() {
        return addresses;
    }

    public void setAddresses(List<String> addresses) {
        this.addresses = addresses;
    }

    public int getTotal() {
        return total;
    }

    public void setTotal(int total) {
        this.total = total;
    }

    public int getFees() {
        return fees;
    }

    public void setFees(int fees) {
        this.fees = fees;
    }

    public int getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public void setSize(int size) {
        this.size = size;
    }

    public String getPreference() {
        return preference;
    }

    public void setPreference(String preference) {
        this.preference = preference;
    }

    public String getRelayed_by() {
        return relayed_by;
    }

    public void setRelayed_by(String relayed_by) {
        this.relayed_by = relayed_by;
    }

    public String getReceived() {
        return received;
    }

    public void setReceived(String received) {
        this.received = received;
    }

    public int getVer() {
        return ver;
    }

    public void setVer(int ver) {
        this.ver = ver;
    }

    public boolean getDouble_spend() {
        return double_spend;
    }

    public void setDouble_spend(boolean double_spend) {
        this.double_spend = double_spend;
    }

    public int getVin_sz() {
        return vin_sz;
    }

    public void setVin_sz(int vin_sz) {
        this.vin_sz = vin_sz;
    }

    public int getVout_sz() {
        return vout_sz;
    }

    public void setVout_sz(int vout_sz) {
        this.vout_sz = vout_sz;
    }

    public int getConfirmations() {
        return confirmations;
    }

    public void setConfirmations(int confirmations) {
        this.confirmations = confirmations;
    }

    public List<Inputs> getInputs() {
        return inputs;
    }

    public void setInputs(List<Inputs> inputs) {
        this.inputs = inputs;
    }

    public List<Outputs> getOutputs() {
        return outputs;
    }

    public void setOutputs(List<Outputs> outputs) {
        this.outputs = outputs;
    }
}
```

Code to MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private String URL = "https://api.blockcypher.com/v1/btc/main/txs/b6f6991d03df0e2e04dafffcd6bc418aac66049e2cd74b80f14ac86db1e3f0da";
private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
private Gson gson;

private static ArrayList<Cyphers> cyphersList = new ArrayList<>();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if(mRequestQueue == null){
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    }

    requestJsonThroughVolley();

}

private void requestJsonThroughVolley(){
    JsonObjectRequest objectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                    gson = new Gson();
                    Cyphers cyphers;
                    cyphers = gson.fromJson(response.toString(), Cyphers.class);

                    String block_height = String.valueOf(cyphers.getBlock_height());
                    String total = String.valueOf(cyphers.getTotal());
                    String fee = String.valueOf(cyphers.getFees());
                    String size = String.valueOf(cyphers.getSize());
                    String received = String.valueOf(cyphers.getReceived());
                    String confirmations = String.valueOf(cyphers.getConfirmations());

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            });

    mRequestQueue.add(objectRequest);
}

private void showalert(String title, String msj)
{
    AlertDialog.Builder MSGbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    MSGbox.setTitle(title);
    String mensaje = msj;
    MSGbox.setMessage(mensaje)
            .setPositiveButton("OKEY", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
    AlertDialog alertDialog = MSGbox.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code if you are using Gson library

```
private void DataAdapter(String json)
{
        JsonObject jsonObject = gson.fromJson(json, JsonElement.class).getAsJsonObject();

        String block_height = jsonObject.get("block_height").getAsString();
        String total = jsonObject.get("total").getAsString();
        String fee = jsonObject.get("fee").getAsString();
        String size = jsonObject.get("size").getAsString();
        String received = jsonObject.get("received").getAsString();
        String confirmations = jsonObject.get("confirmations").getAsString();

        showalert(TxsHashs,received);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, by using your code I could know that was an orthographic error